# Multiple CA certs - How to convert them in single file (may be .pem ) and use them?

Tags: linux, ssl, requests

I am using python `http.client` for making requests to server. I am using multiple ssl_ca certs and I specify them using the `load_verify_locations` multiple times.

However, in python requets only a single file can be given as certs for ssl. How do I convert the multiple .crt files as single file (may be .crt or .pem) ?

Comment: Assuming the files are in PEM format: `cat *.crt > bundle.pem`.

Comment: And if any one is in the .crt format, then copy the contents in the .pem file ?

Comment: There is no .crt format. .crt is a file extension not a format. It is usually either PEM or DER format in this file. To convert between formats use `openssl x509 -in cert.der -inform der -out cert.pem` (again, file extensions don't matter so the input file might also be called cert.crt etc)